# AES-GCM GHASH calculation;

Tags: aes, gcm, aes-gcm

I'm trying to make an GHASH() function and need some clarification. 
Implementation is based on [gcm-spec](http://luca-giuzzi.unibs.it/corsi/Support/papers-cryptography/gcm-spec.pdf). Page 8 describes polynomial mult and page 27 has a "Test Case 2" which I use to verify result.

From my understanding `X1` is a first round of GHASH function and effectively a result of multiplication of 16B of ciphertext and 'H'. From test case

```
X1<-C * H
X1<= '0388dace60b6a392f328c2b971b2fe78' * '66e94bd4ef8a2c3b884cfa59ca342b2e'
```

My implementation gives a different result. I also have tried some online tools which gave a totally different numbers as well :(

So the question is do I got it right that `X1` is a result of `multH(C,H)`?

Thanks

Comment: give me the primitive polynomial that you used please

Comment: @أكرم-آل-كرميش please never post a question as an answer. GCM always uses the polynomial $x^{128} + x^7 + x^2 + x + 1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you a right; also after running the GF(128)/GCM multiplication test I confirm that the product of the test values is

0x0388DACE60B6A392F328C2B971B2FE78 $\times$ 0x66E94BD4EF8A2C3B884CFA59CA342B2E = 0x5E2EC746917062882C85B0685353DEB7

Comment: Alright, nailed it. Need to get used to this reverse bit order of input bit stream. I used `0x80` mask to check for `V[127]==0`. While it's actually a LSB of a last byte and right mask is `0x01`. Thanks, mate.

Comment: 0x... usually indicates hexadecimal (Big Endian) notation, while the gcm-spec seems to run with hex dumps, i.e. leading digit pair refers to polynomial coefficients x^0 ... x^7,  bit order is another story